# VSCode doesn't import <Text> component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx

VSCode with typescript has this awesome feature where if you do `CMD`+`.` on a module that hasn't been imported yet, it gives you the option to automatically import that module or import all modules that are missing.

It's particularly helpful when copying a bunch of JSX, and letting vscode handle all the imports. This works great but with one exception, it won't import the  component. I figured it's probably because it refers to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/Text.

Is there a way to point typescript in the right direction?

**Example below:**

[image: Example]

Comment: Show import part of your file.

Comment: How would that help? In this case its just { Component } from 'react' @hoangdv

Comment: I think, you have to add the line `import React from 'react'` at the first of file, mark this file write in react syntax instead of html

Comment: @hoangdv syntax is already typescript-react because its a tsx file. importing react wouldnt make a difference, otherwise view wouldn't be importable as in the example

Answer (score 0):

Put your `Text.tsx` component in a `path/to/Text/` folder, then rename it to `index.tsx`. This should get VSCode to start suggesting the import.

Comment: The problem is [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/Text) is a built-in, so TS has no incentive to suggest imports because it already exists (in scope).

Comment: @vera. ??? Not on web, and OP didn't tag this `react-native`. I'm guessing OP didn't install @types/react-native and/or is confused about the difference between web and native. The suggestion in this answer is correct if it's a custom React DOM component named "Text".